# FirebaseAuth: Blocked a frame when linking Anonymous with Google

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to link an anonymous user with a Google account. but I am getting the error: **DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:9200" from accessing a cross-origin frame.**

This is what I am doing:

```js
async anonymousSignIn() {
  await signInAnonymously(auth)

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => (this._user = user))
},

async googleSignIn() {
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
  const { isAnonymous } = this._user

  await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then(async (result) => {
      if (isAnonymous) {
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result)

        await linkWithPopup(auth.currentUser, credential)
          .then((usercred) => {
            console.log('Anonymous account successfully upgraded', usercred)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error upgrading anonymous account', error)
          })

        return
      }

      const isNewUser = getAdditionalUserInfo(result)?.isNewUser
      const { email, displayName, photoURL, uid } = result.user

      if (isNewUser) {
        await setDoc(doc(db, 'users', uid), { email, displayName, photoURL })
      } else {
        this._user = {}
      }

      await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', result.user.uid)).then((document) => {
        this.$patch({ _user: { uid: document.id, ...document.data() } })
      })
    })
},
```

Note that the user first calls the `anonymousSignIn()` function. Then after some time it is offered to link with your google account. If he wants to, the `googleSignIn`  function will be called.

As a result, instead of linking the two identifiers (anonymous and @gmail.com), it is creating two separately.

Also, when running the second function, I still get the following errors in the console:

[image: console]

Does anyone know what I'm missing?